# scope ":locale" do reseting my homepage to the "Welcome Aboard" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am trying to set internationalization options on my site, following this railscast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBdZ9_yGLjg. When I add "scope ":locale" do" in the config.routes.rb, restart the server and refresh localhost:3000, I get the original "Welcome Aboard" template.

Config.routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ":locale" do  

    get 'sessions/new'

    root             'welcome_pages#home'
    get 'help'    => 'welcome_pages#help'
    get 'about'   => 'welcome_pages#about'
    get 'contact' => 'welcome_pages#contact'

    get 'signup'  => 'operators#new'
    get 'operators/new'
    resources :operators

    get 'vts/new'
    resources :vts

    get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
    post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
    delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  end 
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
  before_filter :set_locale

  private 

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale}
  end 

end
```

Why is it reverting to the welcoming page?

Answer (score 0):

try the following to set the /:locale optional:

```
#routes.rb
scope "(:locale)" do
  root 'welcome_pages#home'
  ...
end
```

and then

```
#application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :set_locale

  private

    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end

    def default_url_options(options = {})
      { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
    end

end
```

It should fix your problem with root_path reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your routes:

`scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do`